# Minimum page height is viewport height

Tags: html, css

I have I think simple problem but I'm quite confused how to do that.

Like in the snippet `header` should has 130px height and `footer` 20px height. I need to have some `min-width` in my `#landing-page-container` because I need to have my footer at least at the bottom of current view (of course if our `#landing-page-container` will be higher it can be not visible at start).

I have some codepen:

```css
.container{
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100%;
}
#header-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: red;
}
#landing-page-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="header-container">
    Here is some navbar
  </header>
  <section id="landing-page-container">
    Here is some content
  </section>
  <footer id="footer-container">
    Here is footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

I feel a little bit confused with all position and display properties in CSS.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Hi*

To achive this you can calculate minimum content height if you know height of header in footer. Look at snippet below, where is modified your code. You don't even need in this case min height and width for container.

```css
#header-container {
  height: 130px;
  background-color: red;
}
#landing-page-container {
  /*
  We need to calculate content min height.
  It is whole viewport y axis - height of header and footer.
  */
  min-height: calc(100vh - 130px - 20px);
  background-color: blue;
}
#footer-container {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

/* For sample purposes.*/
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="header-container">
    Here is some navbar
  </header>
  <section id="landing-page-container">
    Here is some content
  </section>
  <footer id="footer-container">
    Here is footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

#### *Cheers*

Comment: Thank You very much ! :)  That's what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this using `position: fixed` and adding `width: 100%` to all of the elements:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: -7.51px;
}

#header-container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#landing-page-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header id="header-container">
    Here is some navbar
  </header>
  <section id="landing-page-container">
    Here is some content
  </section>
  <footer id="footer-container">
    Here is footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YawNjr